# Transposing matrix / Trouble understanding how bsxfun works

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, transpose, bsxfun

This could be a weird question because Many would be wondering why to use such a complicated function like `bsxfun` for transposing while you have the `.'` operator.

But, transposing isn't a problem for me. I frame my own questions and try to solve using specific functions so that i learn how the function actually works. I tried solving some examples using `bsxfun` and have succeeded in getting desired results. But my thought, that i have understood how this function works, changed when i tried this example.

The example image i've taken is a square 2D image, so that i'm not trying to access an index which is unavailable.

**Here is my code:**

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(im);
[rows,cols] = size(im);

imout = bsxfun(@(r,c) im(c,r),(1:rows).',1:cols);
```

**Error i got:**

> Error using bsxfun
>   Invalid output dimensions.
>
> Error in test (line 9)
>   imout = bsxfun(@(r,c) im(c,r),(1:rows).',1:cols);

**PS:** I tried interchanging `r` and `c` inside `im( , )` (like this: `bsxfun(@(r,c) im(r,c),(1:rows).',1:cols)`) which didn't pose any error and i got the same exact image as the input.

---

I also tried this using loops and simple transpose using `.'` operator which works perfectly.

**Here is my loopy code:**

```
imout(size(im)) = 0;

for i = 1:rows
    for j = 1:cols
        imout(i,j) = im(j,i);
    end
end
```

Answer i'm expecting is, what is wrong with my code, what does the error signify and how could the code be modified to make it work.

Comment: Nice question. Specially for correctly mentioning `.'` and not `'` :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. I also did some test and found out a solution.  i expect you guys to verify that and correct if i am wrong :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you wrote in your answer. `bsxfun` does _singleton expansion_: it repeats each singleton dimension according to the size of that dimension in the other array. That's all there is to it, I think

Comment: @LuisMendo, yeah.. doc says it **virtually** replicates the array along that dimension to match the other array.. If it had actually replicated, the size would be different.

Comment: Yes, sorry. The replication is only from a functioning point of view. It's not actually replacited (that would be `repmat`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your function doesn't return an output the same shape as the input it is given. Although the requirement for `bsxfun` is that the function operates element-wise, it is not called with scalar elements. So, you need to do this:

```
x = randi(5, 4, 5)
[m, n] = size(x);
bsxfun(@(r, c) transpose(x(c, r)), (1:n)', 1:m)
```

Comment: "Although the requirement for `bsxfun` is that the function operates element-wise, it is not called with scalar elements". That made a lot of sense to me. I did some test and found out the results were exactly same as yours :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`anonymous function`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) like so -

```
%// Create the tranposed indices with BSXFUN
idx = bsxfun(@(r,c) (c-1)*size(im,1)+r,1:rows,(1:cols).') %//'

%// Index into input array with those indices for the final transposed output
imout = im(idx)
```

Comment: hmm :) That would work, +1 but still would you mention why my code isn't working? Also what does the error signify? why isn't matlab giving me the same error when i interchange `r` and `c`? That would make me understand the function little bit more. will u pls?

Comment: @SanthanSalai I wish I had a good answer to the error thing, unfortunately I don't.

Comment: No prob :) i did some test with it and i guess i found out the reason for that error. i have posted it as a solution and i want you guys to verify that and correct if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to know how `bsxfun` works so i created a function like this:

**`bsxfun` test function:**

```
function out = bsxfuntest(r,c)
    disp([size(r) , size(c)]);
    out = r + c;  // just normal addition so that it works fine.
end
```

**My script:**

```
im = magic(5);

[rows,cols] = size(im);

bsxfun(@bsxfuntest ,(1:rows).',1:cols);
```

**Output:**  (not the value of output of the function. These are those which are printed within `bsxfuntest.m` function using `disp`)

```
 5     1     1     1

 5     1     1     1

 5     1     1     1

 5     1     1     1

 5     1     1     1
```

**Conclusion:**

> `bsxfun` passes each column into the function instead of each element.
>
> If either one of the input is a scalar, then the function is called only one time i.e the matrix whether it is 2D or 3D or nD, is passed in one go.

**Try this:**

```
bsxfun(@bsxfuntest , repmat(5,[5 5 5]) ,1);
```

> Also if both the inputs are of same dimensions, then also the function is called only one time.

**Try this:**

```
bsxfun(@bsxfuntest , repmat(5,[5 5 2]) , repmat(2,[5 5 2]))
```

> If none of them is a scalar, and both the inputs are of different dimensions, then The inputs are passed as column vectors.

**Try this:**

```
bsxfun(@bsxfuntest , repmat(5,[5 5 1]) ,permute(1:3,[1 3 2]));
```

**and this:**

```
bsxfun(@bsxfuntest , repmat(5,[5 5 2]) ,permute(1:2,[1 3 2]));
```

**Coming to the problem**

```
>> im

im =

17    24     1     8    15
23     5     7    14    16
 4     6    13    20    22
10    12    19    21     3
11    18    25     2     9
```

**Taking the code in the question:**

```
imout = bsxfun(@(r,c) im(c,r),(1:rows).',1:cols);
```

When i try `im(c,r)` i.e `im(1,(1:5).')`

```
>> im(1,(1:5).')

ans =

17    24     1     8    15
```

Here, `bsxfun` expects a **column vector** while the output is a **row vector**. I guess that is the reason why MatLab produces an error stating

> Invalid output dimensions.

This was also the reason why i didn't get any error when i replaced `r` and `c` in the above code like this `bsxfun(@(r,c) im(r,c),(1:rows).',1:cols)`. Because here, the output was a column vector itself.

So i tried to transpose the results to obtain the column vector like this:

```
>> imout = bsxfun(@(r,c) (im(c,r)).',(1:rows).',1:cols)

imout =

17    23     4    10    11
24     5     6    12    18
 1     7    13    19    25
 8    14    20    21     2
15    16    22     3     9
```

The code is exactly the same as [Edrics's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29984858/2111163) and it gives the expected results.

Comment: Makes some sense now! But, still few things are not exactly clear to me, need to dig deeper I think, to me at least. Also, would be interesting to see how this goes onto more dimensions.

Comment: @Divakar, have you done any further research on this? any strange results? If positive, would you like to share, or may be post as a new topic? could be helpful for many of us.. eagerly waiting :)

Comment: Ah I am sorry, no I haven't. Maybe sometime in the future I might, but no plans as of now, sorry really :)

Comment: @Divakar Thats okay.. no prob :)