# Matlab's bsxfun() - what explains the performance differences when expanding along different dimensions?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization, bsxfun

In my line of work (econometrics/statistics), I frequently have to multiply matrices of different sizes and then perform additional operations on the resulting matrix. I have always relied on `bsxfun()` to vectorize the code, which in general I find it to be more efficient than `repmat()`. But what I don't understand is why sometimes the performance of `bsxfun()` can be very different when expanding the matrices along different dimensions.

Consider this specific example:

```
x      = ones(j, k, m);
beta   = rand(k, m, s);

exp_xBeta   = zeros(j, m, s);
for im = 1 : m
    for is = 1 : s
        xBeta                = x(:, :, im) * beta(:, im, is);
        exp_xBeta(:, im, is) = exp(xBeta);
    end
end

y = mean(exp_xBeta, 3);
```

**Context**:

We have data from *m* markets and within each market we want to calculate the expectation of *exp(X * beta)* where *X* is a *j* x *k* matrix, and *beta* is a *k* x *1* random vector. We compute this expectation by monte-carlo integration - make *s* draws of *beta*, compute *exp(X * beta)* for each draw, and then take the mean. Typically we get data with *m > k > j*, and we use a very large *s*. In this example I simply let *X* to be a matrix of ones.

I did 3 versions of vectorization using `bsxfun()`, they differ by how *X* and *beta* are shaped:

**Vectorization 1**

```
x1      = x;                                    % size [ j k m 1 ]
beta1   = permute(beta, [4 1 2 3]);             % size [ 1 k m s ]

tic
xBeta       = bsxfun(@times, x1, beta1);
exp_xBeta   = exp(sum(xBeta, 2));
y1          = permute(mean(exp_xBeta, 4), [1 3 2 4]);   % size [ j m ]
time1       = toc;
```

**Vectorization 2**

```
x2      = permute(x, [4 1 2 3]);                % size [ 1 j k m ]
beta2   = permute(beta, [3 4 1 2]);             % size [ s 1 k m ]

tic
xBeta       = bsxfun(@times, x2, beta2);
exp_xBeta   = exp(sum(xBeta, 3));
y2          = permute(mean(exp_xBeta, 1), [2 4 1 3]);   % size [ j m ]
time2       = toc;
```

**Vectorization 3**

```
x3      = permute(x, [2 1 3 4]);                % size [ k j m 1 ]
beta3   = permute(beta, [1 4 2 3]);             % size [ k 1 m s ]

tic
xBeta       = bsxfun(@times, x3, beta3);
exp_xBeta   = exp(sum(xBeta, 1));
y3          = permute(mean(exp_xBeta, 4), [2 3 1 4]);    % size [ j m ]
time3       = toc;
```

And this is how they performed (typically we get data with m > k > j, and we used a very large s):

**j = 5, k = 15, m = 100, s = 2000**:

```
For-loop version took 0.7286 seconds.
Vectorized version 1 took 0.0735 seconds.
Vectorized version 2 took 0.0369 seconds.
Vectorized version 3 took 0.0503 seconds.
```

**j = 10, k = 15, m = 150, s = 5000**:

```
For-loop version took 2.7815 seconds.
Vectorized version 1 took 0.3565 seconds.
Vectorized version 2 took 0.2657 seconds.
Vectorized version 3 took 0.3433 seconds.
```

**j = 15, k = 35, m = 150, s = 5000**:

```
For-loop version took 3.4881 seconds.
Vectorized version 1 took 1.0687 seconds.
Vectorized version 2 took 0.8465 seconds.
Vectorized version 3 took 0.9414 seconds.
```

Why is version 2 consistently always the fastest version? Initially, I thought the performance advantage was because *s* was set to dimension 1, which Matlab might be able to compute faster since it stored data in column-major order. But Matlab's profiler told me that the time taken to compute that mean was rather insignificant and was more or less the same among all 3 versions. Matlab spent most of the time evaluating the line with `bsxfun()`, and that's also where the run-time difference was the biggest among the 3 versions.

Any thought on why version 1 is always the slowest and version 2 is always the fastest?

I've updated my test code here:
[Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3574759/bsxfun_test.m)

**EDIT**: earlier version of this post was incorrect. `beta` should be of size `(k, m, s)`.

Answer (score 3):

[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) is of course one of the good tools to vectorize things, but if you can somehow introduce `matrix-multiplication` that would be best way to go about it, as [`matrix multiplications are really fast on MATLAB`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication).

It seems here you can use `matrix-multiplication` to get `exp_xBeta` like so -

```
[m1,n1,r1] = size(x);
n2 = size(beta,2);
exp_xBeta_matmult = reshape(exp(reshape(permute(x,[1 3 2]),[],n1)*beta),m1,r1,n2)
```

Or directly get `y` as shown below -

```
y_matmult = reshape(mean(exp(reshape(permute(x,[1 3 2]),[],n1)*beta),2),m1,r1)
```

**Explanation**

To explain it in a bit more detail, we have the sizes as -

```
x      : (j, k, m)
beta   : (k, s)
```

Our end goal is to use the "eliminate" the k's from `x` and `beta` using `matrix-multiplication`. So, we can "push" the `k` in `x` to the end with `permute` and reshape to a 2D keeping `k` as the rows, i.e. ( j * m , k ) and then perform matrix-multiplication with `beta` ( k , s ) to give us ( j * m , s ). The product can then be reshaped to a 3D array ( j , m , s ) and perform elementwise exponential which would be `exp_xBeta`.

Now, if the final goal is `y`, which is getting the mean along the third dimension of `exp_xBeta`, it would be equivalent to calculating the mean along the rows of the matrix-multiplication product (j * m, s ) and then reshaping to ( j , m ) to get us `y` directly.

Comment: Thanks, using your approach it took less than 0.05 seconds to run. I was under the impression that bsxfun() can perform as fast as matrix multiplication, clearly I was wrong. But I've noticed a mistake in my example code, beta should also be different in each *m*, that is, beta should be a k-by-m-by-s matrix, seems like that would make it much tedious to stack the matrix up to do matrix-multiplication...

Comment: @IvanT So, `beta` would be (k,m,s)? Can you edit the codes in the question accordingly?

Comment: @IvanT Or would be better to append that as a new section?

Comment: I've updated the post and re-ran my code. It seems like the runtimes are more or less the same. The question remains why using `bsxfun()` the way in version 2 is faster than the other 2 approaches. What's the underlying implementation details of `bsxfun()` that causes such difference?

Answer (score 1):

I did some more experiments this morning. It seems that it has to do with the fact that Matlab stores data in column major order after all.

In doing these experiments, I also added vectorization version 4 which does the same thing but orders the dimensions slightly different than versions 1-3.

---

To recap, here are how `x` and `beta` are ordered in all 4 versions:

Vectorization 1:

```
x       :   (j, k, m, 1)
beta    :   (1, k, m, s)
```

Vectorization 2:

```
x       :   (1, j, k, m)
beta    :   (s, 1, k, m)
```

Vectorization 3:

```
x       :   (k, j, m, 1)
beta    :   (k, 1, m, s)
```

Vectorization 4:

```
x       :   (1, k, j, m)
beta    :   (s, k, 1, m)
```

**code** : [bsxfun_test.m](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3574759/bsxfun_test.m)

---

The two most costly operations in this code are:

(a) `xBeta      = bsxfun(@times, x, beta);`

(b) `exp_xBeta  = exp(sum(xBeta, dimK));`

where `dimK` is the dimension of `k`.

In (a), `bsxfun()` has to expand `x` along the dimension of `s` and `beta` along the dimension of `j`. When `s` is much larger than other dimensions, we should see some performance advantage in vectorizations 2 and 4, since they assign `s` as the first dimension.

```
j = 100; k = 100; m = 100; s = 1000;

Vectorized version 1 took 2.4719 seconds.
Vectorized version 2 took 2.1419 seconds.
Vectorized version 3 took 2.5071 seconds.
Vectorized version 4 took 2.0825 seconds.
```

If instead `s` is trivial and `k` is huge, then vectorization 3 should be the fastest since it puts `k` in dimension 1:

```
j = 10; k = 10000; m = 100; s = 1;

Vectorized version 1 took 0.0329 seconds.
Vectorized version 2 took 0.1442 seconds.
Vectorized version 3 took 0.0253 seconds.
Vectorized version 4 took 0.1415 seconds.
```

If we swap the value of `k` and `j` in the last example, vectorization 1 becomems the fastest since `j` is assigned to dimension 1:

```
j = 10000; k = 10; m = 100; s = 1;

Vectorized version 1 took 0.0316 seconds.
Vectorized version 2 took 0.1402 seconds.
Vectorized version 3 took 0.0385 seconds.
Vectorized version 4 took 0.1608 seconds.
```

But in general when `k` and `j` are close, `j > k` does not necessary imply vectorization 1 is faster than vectorization 3 since the operations performed in (a) and (b) are different.

In practice, I often have to run computation with `s >>>> m > k > j`. In such cases, it seems that ordering them in vectorization 2 or 4 gives the best results:

```
    j = 10; k = 30; m = 100; s = 5000;

Vectorized version 1 took 0.4621 seconds.
Vectorized version 2 took 0.3373 seconds.
Vectorized version 3 took 0.3713 seconds.
Vectorized version 4 took 0.3533 seconds.

    j = 15; k = 50; m = 150; s = 5000;

Vectorized version 1 took 1.5416 seconds.
Vectorized version 2 took 1.2143 seconds.
Vectorized version 3 took 1.2842 seconds.
Vectorized version 4 took 1.2684 seconds.
```

---

**Takeaway**: if `bsxfun()` has to expand along a dimension of size much bigger than other dimensions, assign that dimension to dimension 1!

Answer (score 1):

Refer this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29982866/2111163) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29987936/2111163)

If you are gonna process matrices of different dimensions using `bsxfun`, make sure that the biggest dimension of the matrices is kept in first dimension.

**Here is my small example test:**

```
%// Inputs
%// Taking one very big and one small vector, so that the difference could be seen clearly
a = rand(1000000,1);
b = rand(1,5);

%//---------------- testing with inbuilt function
%// preferred orientation [1]
t1 = timeit(@() bsxfun(@times, a, b))

%// not preferred [2]
t2 = timeit(@() bsxfun(@times, b.', a.'))

%//---------------- testing with anonymous function
%// preferred orientation [1]
t3 = timeit(@() bsxfun(@(x,y) x*y, a, b))

%// not preferred [2]
t4 = timeit(@() bsxfun(@(x,y) x*y, b.', a.'))
```

<sup>[1] Preferred orientation      -     larger dimension as first dimension

[2] Not preferred                 -     smaller dimension as first dimension</sup>

> **Small Note:** The output given by all four methods are same even though their dimensions may differ.

**Results:**

```
t1 =
0.0461

t2 =
0.0491

t3 =
0.0740

t4 =
7.5249

>> t4/t3
ans =
101.6878
```

---

`Method 3` is roughly **100 times faster** than `Method 4`

---

> **To conclude:**
>   Although the difference between preferred and unfavored orientation for built-in function is minimum,
>   The difference becomes huge for anonymous function. So it might be a best practice to use bigger dimension as dimension 1.